# How to pair device bluetooth and send data

Tags: bluetooth

I'm not learning about android, I'm writing a small bluetooth app, but there are some issues that need help.
  - I have received the Paired Devices on the list, but don't know how to pair with it (I use HC-05 Bluetooth Module).
  - Someone helped me fix it a little bit.
    + when clicking on the Bluetooth icon on the side of the show. I want it to pair with that device and toast out.(I was build interface and some function in file below)
    + If possible, please write me a function that sends data through the connected device
Project me to below,
[Link Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fUZSOS1Eau3hiWZURdYhANQurK9L5xh9/view?usp=sharing)

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Android studio, but I know MIT App inventor. I made a video about android program to connect HC-06 and HC-05. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWCdTJgn8oM
If you install the program on your android, you must tap Text for ListPicker1. Thereafter you must search HC-05 in List, and tap.